# How to send a bluetooth ACK signal (standard formats?)

Tags: node.js, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate with a bluetooth thermometer. It's not BLE, it uses serial ports. I've made it as far as receiving REQ signals from the device, but it requires a ACK signal or it cuts the connection after a few seconds.

The problem is, I can't decipher what the ACK signal is supposed to be. Going off the documentation, it says:

`<ACK Format> ADH,01H`

`<REQ Format> ADH,00H,n`
`The third byte of REQ is the can be multiplied by 0.01310547 to get the voltage of the battery`

`<Data Format> ADH,03H,1EH," IRSTP3xx.yyy.HhhSss,nnn,tt.t"+0D+0A
xx: LotNo.(base 16) "01"~"FF"
yyy: S/N(base 16) "001"~"FFF"
...
...`

Nothing in the Data Format mentions the first 3 bytes(?) either.

That's pretty much all I've got to work with. I'm trying decoding REQ with different encodings like ascii and utf-8 to see if I can get it to match the REQ format, and then use that same encoding to format and send ACK, but I haven't had any luck.

Is the format just in some kind of standard notation that I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

The H apparently stands for hexidecimal.
ADH is a two byte message, the first byte being a hex A and the second a hex D. I have not seen that notation before.